# cartopy and xarray issues

Tags: python, netcdf, cartopy, xarray

I'm beginning to use netCDF4 data and therefore I have downloaded `xarray` and also `cartopy` (with pip).

I have downloaded data from the [climate data store](https://climate.copernicus.eu/climate-data-store) and want to plot these data.

I have a notebook on which I'm working and have narrowed the problem to this :

If I run

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('my_path_to_cds_data.nc')
```

Everything's fine.
But if I do :

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('my_path_to_cds_data.nc')
```

I get the following error :

```
OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'my_path_to_cds_data.nc'
```

It looks kind of weird. One clue might be that I had to add the unstable ppa of ubuntugis as I'm working with `rasterio`.

If this kind of issue looks familiar I'd be glad to have some help !

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out,

It indeed comes from the unstable version of ubuntugis, the version of `cartopy` from this repo does not seem to work, I removed the ppa and downgraded the libs and made a fresh install. It works right now but I can't use `rasterio`, I'll try to find a warkaround